# Strings in If - Else Statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax, statements

I am writing a program that takes a user input and depending on their answer gives them a different answer. How do I use a string that the user entered with an if - else statement?

I have this so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

class t1_lesson07_template{

     public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

              Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

              System.out.print("Hello, welcome to the companion planting guide. ");
              System.out.print("Lets get started! To begin, just input the desired plant in the box to learn what plants to grow with it!");
              String plant = scan.nextLine();
              if (plant == "Asparagus") {
                System.out.print("Tomatoes, parsley, and basil.");
              }


     }

}
```

I am wondering about the syntax for the if statement in this case.

Comment: Did you bother looking up "if syntax java" on the internet? why not try compiling this?

Comment: checkout this awesome post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator in Java checks that two references are **the same**. `equals(Object)`, on the other hand, checks that two references are **equal**.

In your case, there's no guarantee that the string `Asparagus` inputed from the user and the hard-coded literal in your code will, in fact, be the same object, so `==` is wrong, and you should use `equals(Object)`:

```
if (plant.equals("Asparagus")) {
    System.out.print("Tomatoes, parsley, and basil.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

change this    `plant == "Asparagus"`

to

```
plant.equals("Asparagus")
```

compare the String with `equals();`

Answer (score 0):

[Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are objects in Java. It is easy to mistake it for a primitive because it is a part of the "default" `java.lang` class. To compare Strings (as with all objects) you need to use the `.equals` method.

What the equality operator does in this case is to compare between the addresses of String variable `plant` and the new String object it allocated just for that line, `"Asparagus"`. Of course, as they are different objects, they will never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

"==" -> is just comparasion of the pointers (object reference)

"s1.equals(s2)" -> is the comparasion of the content